# Makefile - behavior without additional arguments

Tags: c, command-line, makefile, arguments

How can I define the behavior of running `make` with no additional arguments?

I tried to do something like:

```
:
    ./someprogram
.PHONY:
```

In order to run `someprogram` in case of running `make` without arguments but I get the following error:
`Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: if you don't specify an argument to make, the __first__ target will be built.

Comment: And if I want the make to run previously built program in this case, is this possible?

Comment: And you need to have a *named* target, even the "default" first target needs to have a name. And it could depend on the program you're building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile should look something as below:

```
all:
    @echo Running test program
    ./someprogram
    @echo program ended..

.PHONY:all
```

Comment: But I don't want `make all` to run my program. I want `make` to run it.

Comment: @KobiT If you just type make it will still work, by default all rule will be called (you don’t need to type make all, just make will automatically call the all rule)

Comment: Just to be clear, there's nothing special about the target `all`.  If you don't specify a target to build, then make will build the first explicit target defined in the makefile, whatever it's called.  It so happens that `all` is a commonly used name for the first target in the makefile, but it's by no means universal and has no special meaning to make.